# Deleted file remains in NSBundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsbundle

I recently deleted a file within Xcode. After I deleted this file I cleaned up the project (Shift+cmd+K). For one or other reason the system shows the warning after the cleaning process has been finished successfully:

no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/json2.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386

But this is not the deleted file since I deleted 1231345.jpg

I use the following code to check if the path exists

```
if([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1231345" ofType:@"jpg"] == NULL)
{
     //Here some code if the image doesn't exist
} else {
     //Here some code if the image does exist
}
```

If I manually change the 'pathForResource' to a random number which hasn't been a previous file everything works fine!

Whats going wrong here?

Comment: This did work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000881/cant-remove-files-from-mainbundle

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted the app in the simulator/device? If you deploy via XCode, old files are not deleted, but if you build & archive and then install the archive it usually works.